# Concatenate multiple CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Say I have this html :

```
<div class="div">
    <div class="sub-div"></div>
    <div class="sub-div"></div>
    <div class="extra-sub-div"></div>
</div>
```

Currently if I want to get the second sub-div, I can do this :

```
.div .sub-div:nth-child(2) {
  attribute: value;
  (...)
}
```

Now, if I want the extra sub-div, I can do this :

```
.div .extra-sub-div {
  attribute: value;
  (...)
}
```

---

Now let's assume the attribute and value of the css **is the same for all**.

Something like :

```
width: 80px;
```

What is the css to write to gather all these div in one, instead of writing multiple css like this :

1.

```
.div .sub-div:nth-child(1) {
  width: 80px;
}
```

2. 

```
.div .sub-div:nth-child(2) {
  width: 80px;
}
```

3. 

```
.div .extra-sub-div {
  width: 80px;
}
```

?

Comment: you can add more than one class to one element. so in the extra-sub-div you can add the .sub-div class

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to concat them, but you can have a class call `.width-80 { width:80px }` and apply that class to all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you group CSS selectors, you apply the same styles to several different elements without repeating the styles in your stylesheet. Instead of having two, three, or more CSS rules that do the same thing (set the width of something to 80px, for example), you use a single CSS rule that accomplishes the same thing.

To group CSS selectors in a style sheet, use commas to separate multiple grouped selectors in the style.

```
.div .sub-div:nth-child(1), .div .sub-div:nth-child(2), .div .extra-sub-div {
  width: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**div >**

```css
.div > div {
  color: red;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
    <div class="sub-div">1</div>
    <div class="sub-div">2</div>
    <div class="extra-sub-div">3</div>
</div>
```

**Ends with '-div':**

```css
div[class$="-div"] {
  color: green;
  width: 80px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
    <div class="sub-div">1</div>
    <div class="sub-div">2</div>
    <div class="extra-sub-div">3</div>
  <div class="extra-sub-no">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `,` for each element you need like:

```css
.div .sub-div:nth-child(1), .div .sub-div:nth-child(2), .div .extra-sub-div {
  width: 80px;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
    <div class="sub-div">1</div>
    <div class="sub-div">2</div>
    <div class="extra-sub-div">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.div div{
   width: 80px;
}
```

This CSS will select .div .sub-div:nth-child(1), .div .sub-div:nth-child(2), .div .extra-sub-div with

Comment: Basically all the children of element "div" of the parent div with class named "div"

Answer (score 1):

I would personally just add another class into the child `div`-elements, separated with a space. This way you're not targetting all of the child `div`-elements, but only the ones with this exact class.

This is good if you have child elements in the parent `div` and you don't want them to have the styling from the `.red-class`-class:

```css
.red-class {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <div class="red-class sub-div">text</div>
  <div class="red-class sub-div">text</div>
  <div class="red-class extra-sub-div">text</div>
  <div class="extra-sub-div">text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is not so clear.

I assume the most appropriate for you is to select the first level of of divs like:

```
 .div > div {
    width: 80px;
}
```

or if you want the first three items

```
.div div:nth-child(-n+3) {
    width: 80px;
}
```

Anyway, there are a lot of sites which can help you with tips in css:
ex:

https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/